# can someone help me with a function that clicks on a button and gets the right photo ( berlin button to get berlin.jpg) inside a div

Tags: javascript, html, css

so i have this code

```
<div class="place-container">
          <h1>PICK YOUR FAVOURITE</h1>
          <p>Select the place you want to get a ticket</p>
          <button class="btn-places" id="berlin">BERLIN</button>
          <button class="btn-places" id="netherlands">NETHERLANDS</button>
          <button class="btn-places" id="sweden">SWEDEN</button>
          <button class="btn-places" id="italy">ITALY</button>
        </div>
```

and i have right this code in js for selecting a button and a get a border

```
for (let i = 0; i < btnPlaces.length; i++) {
  btnPlaces[i].addEventListener("click", function (e) {
    let prevBtn = document.querySelector(".checked");
    console.log(prevBtn);
    if (prevBtn) {
      prevBtn.classList.remove("checked");
      e.target.classList.add("checked");
    } else {
      e.target.classList.add("checked");
    }
  });
}
```

css code

```
.checked {
  border: 3px solid rgb(34, 34, 34);
}
```

now i want to make or add to the function , the ability to show different photos based on the buttons to a div. lets call it (col-1)

for example
i click berlin button and in div col-1 it shows berlin.jpg but when i click sweden it will show sweden and not berlin

Comment: "*I want*" is not a good way to describe your problem and is almost guaranteed your post to be closed rather fast.  Show us what you already tried to solve your **ultimate** task and where exactly you are stuck.

Comment: well i have tried some things but the point is . i want something that will be more effiecient . like a loop that will get every image based of text maybe (so berlin with berlin.jpg)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So assuming the `id` of each button is associated with the picture name you can simply do something like this with js:

```
document.querySelector('.place-container').addEventListener('click', e => {
  if (e.target.classList.contains('btn-places')) {    
    var img = document.getElementById("thePicture");
    img.src = 'img/' + e.target.id + '.jpg';
  }
});
```

If its not associated with the ID but the innerHTML of the button then replace

`img.src = 'img/' + e.target.id + '.jpg';` with

`img.src = 'img/' + e.target.innerHTML + '.jpg';`

Then you said you had something like this in your html with a `div` with id `col-1` so you need to add an `img` in there where you will edit the `src` with the js code above:

```
<div id="col-1">
<img id="thePicture" src="">
</div>
```

Here's a working example (you can right click and inspect the picture to see that the filepath is indeed updating.)

```js
document.querySelector('.place-container').addEventListener('click', e => {
  if (e.target.classList.contains('btn-places')) {    
    var img = document.getElementById("thePicture");
    img.src = 'img/' + e.target.id + '.jpg';
  }
});
```

```html
<div class="place-container" id="piccon">
          <h1>PICK YOUR FAVOURITE</h1>
          <p>Select the place you want to get a ticket</p>
          <button class="btn-places"  id="berlin">BERLIN</button>
          <button class="btn-places"  id="netherlands">NETHERLANDS</button>
          <button class="btn-places"  id="sweden">SWEDEN</button>
          <button class="btn-places"  id="italy">ITALY</button>
        </div>

<div id="col-1">
<img id="thePicture" src="">
</div>
```

Comment: hey brother do you have any idea why it give me this error? netherlands.jpg:1          GET http://127.0.0.1:5500/cs50homepage/cs50homepage/.image/netherlands.jpg 404 (Not Found)

Comment: @NickGlav This looks like you're file path isn't correct maybe? Is it only for this picture and the other pictures work?